# copy multiple directories into one folder from a variable or loop array in bash?

Tags: bash, rsync, array

I am trying to target 100+ directories to perform a copy. The whole script needs to be contained within one file; therefore, I can't have the directories saved in a separate file. I want to be able to edit this script in the future and easily add additional directories later. Some directories have spaces in them.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(
/dir/subdir1/anotherdir/*/.log
~/dir/subdir/file.t
/dir2/subdir2/anotherdir/*/.db
/dir2/some dir here/another/here*.*
...
...
)
dest=( my@destination)

rsync -args "$dirs" $dest
```

I have tried using `"${dirs[@]}"` but I think I might be using it incorrectly since I'm not able to achieve any successful results.

Comment: `"$dirs"` would be correct in `yash`. In `zsh` (where the `array=(...)` syntax comes from in the early 90s), `$dirs`. In `bash`, you do need `"${dirs[@]}"` (which works in all three shells and is from ksh in the early 80s).

Comment: In which way is it not working with `"${dirs[@]}"`? Do you get an error? Does it transfer the wrong files? Have you tried running with `bash -x` to see what `rsync` command is actually run?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So i'm trying to improve my script because I had the rsync command written out 100+ times with arguments. However after switching to using arrays I noticed that some files are not being copied. After looking deeper into which directories are being missed, its the directories using letter case matching in brackets. Example: `/private/var/folders/[a-z][0-9]/*/0/db/db` Directories that are using brackets are not being copied. Previously I was using `rsync -Ra /private/var/folders/[a-z][0-9]/*/0/db/db ~/my/dest` and the copy was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using paths with spaces between folders or filenames you should use the backslash `\` to specify a space. You can also use `'dir space'` or `"dir space"` only in the filename where you have the spaces. About your `$dirs` variable you must use in `"${dirs[@]}"` not `"$dirs"` to get all the paths.

**Solution using backlash:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(
/dir/subdir1/anotherdir/*/.log
~/dir/subdir/file.t
/dir2/subdir2/anotherdir/*/.db
/dir2/some\ dir\ here/another/here*.*
...
...
)
dest=("user@hostname:destination")

rsync -args "${dirs[@]}" "${dest[@]}"
#"${dest[@]}" is useful here because dest var has one item.
#or you can use ${dest[someindex]}:
rsync -args "${dirs[@]}" "${dest[0]}"
```

**Solution using double quotes or single quotes:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(
/dir/subdir1/anotherdir/*/.log
~/dir/subdir/file.t
/dir2/subdir2/anotherdir/*/.db
/dir2/"some dir here"/another/here*.*
/dir2/'some dir here'/another/here*.*
...
...
)
dest=("user@hostname:destination")

rsync -args "${dirs[@]}" "${dest[@]}"
#"${dest[@]}" is useful here because dest var has one item.
#or you can use ${dest[someindex]}:
rsync -args "${dirs[@]}" "${dest[0]}"
```

**Note:** You don't really have to use an array to assign the destination, you can simply use: `dest='my@destination'`

Comment: Note that if `my@destination` is a username and hostname, i.e. some remote system, then this must be followed by `:`. Otherwise you'll get a local copy in a directory called `my@destination`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks :D! I will update the answer. I did assign to `my@destination` because the OP has that. The user might have the correct syntax but it should be useful If I correct that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks! About `$dest` in `zsh`, is this not  short for `${dest[@]}`? and in `bash`  `$dest` is short for `${dest[0]}` is not? I've tested that in both shells and works as I said.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon sorry, I meant ksh/bash. zsh array  design is indeed much more sensible. `$dest` is more `$dest[*]` there. When quoted (or more generally when not in list contexts) elements are joined with the first character of `$IFS`, not separated out like in `"${dest[@]}"` or `yash`'s `"$dest"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wow, that's great! I had no idea about the use `IFS`  with quoted arrays in zsh. Thanks again :D

Comment: ksh/bash/zsh/yash's `"${array[*]}"` like `"$*"` in POSIX shells (from ksh) are also joining with the first character of `$IFS`. In the Bourne shell, that was with spaces. Behaviour varies between shell when `${array[*]}` is unquoted in non-list contexts like in here documents or assignments to scalar variables.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks again. That's very useful, I will put it into practice, It's like `join` method in python :D.

Comment: With `zsh`, you'd use `${(j[separator])array}` rather than modifying the global `$IFS` variable. Also note that some shells don't support joining with multibyte characters. zsh's `j` parameter expansion flag can join with any string, not just single character/byte.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's great! Do you have some links about the zsh's features? I've seen your answers using that shell and it's great what zsh can do.
I would like to know how I can find information about `=` in zsh. For example, if I do: `echo =mkdir` this will show `/usr/bin/mkdir`. (this one according to $PATH variable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote strings containing spaces. It's slightly more complicated here because you must not quote the wildcards.

So,

```
dirs=(
    /dir/subdir1/anotherdir/*/.log
    ~/dir/subdir/file.t
    /dir2/subdir2/anotherdir/*/.db
    '/dir2/some dir here/another'/here*.*
)
```

And because this is an array, you reference all its components with `"${dirs[@]}"` (the double quotes are necessary).

The same applies to `$dest` since you've assigned an array to it. But you'd be better leaving that as a scalar, `dest='/some/path'`